# What are the boundaries of the sets...

Tags: complex-analysis

What are the boundaries of the sets:

**(1)** $|z+3|<2$

**(2)** $|{\bf Im}(z)|<1$

**(3)** $0<|z-1|<2$

**(4)** $|z-1|+|z+1|=2$

**(5)** $|z-1|+|z+1|<3$

**(6)** ${\bf Re}(z)+1\geq|z|$

Comment: You have been given a definition in terms of topology for this?  It's considered bad form to list a number of problem parts with no effort shown to solve any of them.  If nothing else you should have tried to delineate which parts are easier than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a)$|z+3|=2$

(b)$|{\bf Im}(z)|=1$

(c)$|z-1|=2$ and $z=1$

(d)$|z-1|=2$ and $|z+1|=2$

(e)$|z-1|=3$ and $|z+1|=3$

(f)$Re(z)-|z|$=-1

Comment: Please do never ask such a question within an answer. The upvotes or downvotes or comments will tell you if it is correct or not.

Comment: what do you think

Answer (score 1):

What are the boundaries of the sets:

**(1)** $|z+3|=2$

**(2)** $|{\bf Im}(z)|=1$

**(3)** $|z-1|=2$ and $z=1$